# Sharing to Facebook a article using swift

Tags: facebook, swift, sharing

I'm looking to have a share to Facebook button in my app but, I'm looking to have a way that when the screen comes up to share that it'll include the current article and the picture that is in the article too. I'm trying to do this is swift. If someone could please give me a hand with this that would be great!

Comment: This is way too broad; please describe what specifically you are having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that. The following passage was quoted from developers.facebook.com.

> After discussing this with our team regarding stripping the
>   pre-filling message area of text, this is actually BY DESIGN with the
>   new share extension.
>
> Pre-filling texts violates Platform Policy 2.3
>   (https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) to pre-fill the message area
>   with text for people to edit, which is why we strip the text. We know
>   this is a pain point for developers but this is about ensuring that
>   users are sharing exactly what they want to share on Facebook, and not
>   being able to accidentally share text they did not approve of. So in
>   all enforcing policy 2.3 is a feature and not a bug.
>
> Other services may allow you to accomplish this pre-fill but we have
>   updated the share sheet implementation to adhere to the same rules as
>   you would have when sharing directly using the iOS Facebook
>   Application instead of the native share sheet.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/949486035103197/

Comment: That is about the message part of a post or share only. If you let users share a link, you can of course specify the link’s title, description and thumbnail image.